# Ajax callback can't find Authorization header

Tags: ajax, wcf, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I try to consume a WCF service (REST) using ajax (xmlHttpRequest). The service require Basic authentication.

my ajax call is :

```
 var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                 if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
                     //do some stuff
                 }
             }

         };
         httpRequest.open('PUT', 'http://localhost:59000/v1/users/1', true, 'user1', 'user1');
         httpRequest.withCredentials = "true";
         //must authenticate both..in open() but also set header manually ...cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358550/xmlhttp-request-basic-authentication-issue
         httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Auhtorization', 'Basic user1:user1');
         httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
         // overridemimeType() does not set content type header .... don't know why ?
         httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         var params = { "UserName": "user1" };
         var requestBodyString = JSON.stringify(params);
         httpRequest.send(requestBodyString);
```

The way I first handle the request on the server side is the following

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                      crossDomain);

        //preflight request : cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control 
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                          "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, DummyOneForTest");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
                          "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

My browser sends me the error "Request header field Auhtorization is not allwed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" but as you can see it is whitin the response header.

Moreover when I try with Fiddler everything is fine and I even have the header dummy one allowed.

So I am really confused, if anyone can help, please do !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, while running you server on "use visual studio development server" exception is thrown when you try to add a header (second code block) : "this operation require IIS integrated pipeline mode".

the solution is in the app config to "use IIS web server"

Accordingly to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx#addexceptionscommand

You can not ask Visual Studio to tell you when exception is thrown and I missed it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not relevant, but the Ajax snippet above also misspells the header name as "Auhtorization" instead of "Authorization".

Comment: you are right but it did not solve the problem. Thanks anyway