# Providing authentication info via msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP

Tags: api, asp-classic

I am using Classic ASP and trying to use the JustGiving API.

I'd like to use it to display the total amount raised, and total donations received on my donation page, on my website.

I can see that info is available via:
https://api.justgiving.com/docs/resources/v1/Account/Retrieve

```
<%
vurl = "http://api.justgiving.com/---myIDhere---/v1/account"
Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", vurl, False
http.Send

Set dom = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument")

dom.loadXML http.responseText

Set items = dom.getElementsByTagName("account")

For Each item In items

    Set var_totalDonated = item.getElementsByTagName("totalDonated")
    If NOT (var_totalDonated IS Nothing) Then
        var_totalDonated = ap(totalDonated(0).Text)
        response.write var_totalDonated
    End If

Next
%>
```

However, the page times out when I access it.

I think it's because I need to provide some authentication information as detailed here:
https://api.justgiving.com/docs/usage#protectedResources

So I got that authentication info.

But I have no idea how to "send" it to the API, so that it can authenticate me as a user and provide the info.

It also mentions providing info on the header via the link above this one (I can't post the link as I don't have enough reputation), but replace #protectedResources at the end of the URL with #contentTypes.

I'm sorry - am I also missing something on that side?

I'm sorry if I'm asking silly questions, but the info on the API docs assumes some level of intelligence on the part of the user, and I don't have a lot of it!

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

---

Thanks to John for your reply.

Based on that, I changed the code to:

```
<%
vurl = "https://api.justgiving.com/API_KEY/v1/account"
Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", vurl, False, "username", "pwd"
http.setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 10000, 10000 ''ms - resolve, connect, send, receive
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic MY_AUTH_STRING"
http.Send

Set dom = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument")

dom.loadXML http.responseText

Set items = dom.getElementsByTagName("account")

For Each item In items

    Set var_totalDonated = item.getElementsByTagName("totalDonated")
    If NOT (var_totalDonated IS Nothing) Then 
        var_totalDonated = (var_totalDonated(0).Text)
        response.write var_totalDonated
    End If

Next
%>
```

But unfortunately the page still times out.

I'm checking also via:
groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/justgiving-api/Xhz5Fkxuy1s

But no answer so far.

Thanks again

---

## Fixed Version

```
<%

Sub debug( varName )
    Dim varValue
    varValue = Eval( varName )
    response.write "<p style='margin:10px; border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;background-color:white;padding:10px;color:red;text-align:left;'><strong>" & varName & "</strong>: " & varvalue & "</p>" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
End Sub

vurl = "https://api.justgiving.com/AP_KEY/v1/account"
Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", vurl, False, username, password
http.setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 10000, 10000 'ms - resolve, connect, send, receive
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic AUTH_STRING"
http.Send

Response.ContentType = "application/xml"

Set dom = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument")

dom.loadXML http.responseText

Set items = dom.getElementsByTagName("account")

For Each item In items

    Set var_totalDonated = item.getElementsByTagName("totalDonated")
    If NOT (var_totalDonated IS Nothing) Then 
        var_totalDonated = ap(var_totalDonated(0).Text)
        debug "var_totalDonated"
    End If

    Set var_totalRaised = item.getElementsByTagName("totalRaised")
    If NOT (var_totalRaised IS Nothing) Then 
        var_totalRaised = ap(var_totalRaised(0).Text)
        debug "var_totalRaised"
    End If

    Set var_totalGiftAid = item.getElementsByTagName("totalGiftAid")
    If NOT (var_totalGiftAid IS Nothing) Then 
        var_totalGiftAid = ap(var_totalGiftAid(0).Text)
        debug "var_totalGiftAid"
    End If

Next
%>
```

Previously I was using:

```
vurl = "https://api.justgiving.com/AP_KEY/v1/account"
```

But when I changed it to https it worked.

I thought I had tried that previously, but obviously not.

Thanks again to John, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
http.Open "GET", vurl, False, "yourusername", "yourpassword"
```

I don't know if this works on justgiving, but it does with the Bing API

Also, this question may be relevant
[XmlHttp Request Basic Authentication Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358550/xmlhttp-request-basic-authentication-issue)

Edit - using Response.ContentType and Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

```
vurl = "https://api.justgiving.com/API_KEY/v1/account"
Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.Open "GET", vurl, False, "username", "pwd"
http.setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 10000, 10000 'ms - resolve, connect, send, receive'
http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic MY_AUTH_STRING"
http.Send

Response.ContentType = "application/xml"    

Set items = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("account")
```

etc

Comment: Thanks John for your help. I updated the page again based on that but the page still times out :-( I have edited my post above to show the updates. Hopefully it is nearly there - I have asked via the API Google Groups page, and will see if they can help too. Thanks again

Comment: Again, I don't know if it will make any difference, but try "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" and "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0" in your Server.CreateObject statements, particularly if you're on IIS7 or 8 - it means you're using the latest version of msxml.  Once you have it working I recommend you look at server side XSLT transformations, which Classic ASP does rather nicely, rather than parsing directly, but get your http request working first - one step at a time

Comment: Also, try Response.ContentType rather than creating a new XML object, I've edited my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: Hi John, thanks so much for your help. I got it working with your help, and edited my original post to show the working code. In the end it worked once I connected to https instead of http on the JustGiving side. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for adding to an old post. However this has consistently come up when Googling for help on MailChimp API V3.0 and VBA.

This is the fix I used:

```
ret = objhttp.Open("POST", sURL, False) 
objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"

'V3 API uses HTTP Basic Authorisation inside an https: wrapper.
'The standard windows method does not seem to work however the 
'following hack does.
'In summary the user name and APIkey are seperated with a Colon: and 
'base 64 encoded and added to a Http RequestHeader


objhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(APIUser & ":" & ApiKey)

objhttp.send (sJson)
```

You will need to code the Base64Encode function. I grabbed some code from http://pastie.org/1192157 (Ex StackOverflow) and pasted it into a VBA Module.

Hope it helps.