# How to logon webapi from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I try to get data from WebAPI in SQL. When I request WebAPI link, it wants an authentiction from me. I use below script. How can I add authentication user to this script? Thank you.

[Authentication screen in web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ5Wd.png)

Code:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @Body as varchar(8000) = 
'{
    "Subsystem": 1,
    "Exception": "",
    "Message": "I have done what you asked",
    "Time": "2014-06-09T11:16:35",
    "Attribute": { "Number of attempts": "0" }
}'  

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC  sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post','http://server/ws/v1/GET_DATA', 'false'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: i want to pass username and password from sql. i have searched in web but i couldn't find anything. that webapi wants basic authentication and i need to pass that username and password.

Answer (score 2):

As the popup indicates, the site is using Basic authentication. This is implemented as a request header:

```
Authorization: Basic `base64(user:pass)`
```

As explained in [Providing authentication info via msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712635/providing-authentication-info-via-msxml2-serverxmlhttp), to set this header, you can simply call `setRequestHeader` on the object like you already do for the content-type.

Now to create the authorization string, you need to concatenate the string "Basic ", the username, a colon and the password. How to do so in T-SQL is explained in [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql).

Note that by always providing the Authorization header you're basically bypassing authentication entirely. Actually the flow should be like this:

1. Perform an unauthenticated request
2. Receive either a success status code (done) or a 401 Unauthorized
3. Inspect the response headers of that 401 response: it should be `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` (or others, which you'll also need to support)
4. Re-issue the request with the `Authorization: Basic ...` header.

So I'd rather just use a full blown HTTP client that properly handles this, as opposed to hand-crafting HTTP requests from T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue with below codes.

```
CREATE proc HTTPRequest
      @URI varchar(2000) = '',      
      @methodName varchar(50) = '', 
      @requestBody varchar(8000) = '', 
      @SoapAction varchar(255), 
      @UserName nvarchar(100), -- Domain\UserName or UserName 
      @Password nvarchar(100), 
      @responseText varchar(8000) output
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF    @methodName = ''
BEGIN
      select FailPoint = 'Method Name must be set'
      return
END
set   @responseText = 'FAILED'
DECLARE @objectID int
DECLARE @hResult int
DECLARE @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objectID OUT
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                  source = @source, 
                  description = @desc, 
                  FailPoint = 'Create failed', 
                  MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
-- open the destination URI with Specified method 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName, @URI, 'false', @UserName, @Password
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'Open failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
-- set request headers 
--EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'

IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
-- set soap action 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', @SoapAction 
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
declare @len int
set @len = len(@requestBody) 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Length', @len 
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END

-- send the request 
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody 
IF    @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'Send failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
declare @statusText varchar(1000), @status varchar(1000) 
-- Get status text 
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'StatusText', @statusText out
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'Status', @status out
--select @status, @statusText, @methodName --kapattım
-- Get response text 
exec sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'responseText', @responseText out
IF @hResult <> 0 
BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
      SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
            source = @source, 
            description = @desc, 
            FailPoint = 'ResponseText failed', 
            MedthodName = @methodName 
      goto destroy 
      return
END
destroy: 

select @responseText
SELECT DECOMPRESS ( Attachment, 'gzip' )
FROM @responseText;
--select NAME , StringValue from parseJSON(@responseText)

     exec sp_OADestroy @objectID 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: sounds familiar: http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2009/12/22/Call-a-webservice-from-TSQL-(Stored-Procedure)-using-MSXML.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> exec CALLWEBSERVICE 'username','password'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CALLWEBSERVICE(@Username NVARCHAR(50), @Password NVARCHAR(50))
AS
    BEGIN
    Declare @Object as Int;
    DECLARE @authHeader VARCHAR(8000);   
    DECLARE @contentType VARCHAR(8000);
    DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(4000);
    Declare @json as table(response nvarchar(max))

    SET @postData = '{"method":"GetUserVehicles","userid":"1323","companyid":"0"}';   
    SET @contentType = 'application/json';
    SET @authHeader = @Username + ':' + @Password;
   
    SELECT
        @authHeader = 'BASIC ' + CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
              'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
            , 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
        )  
    FROM (
    SELECT
        CAST(@authHeader AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS bin 
    ) AS bin_sql_server_temp;

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', 'http://yourdomain.com/api','false'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send' , NULL, @postData
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO @json (response) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
    SELECT  * FROM @json
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
END
```