# How to pass ASMX services security username & password in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created asmx services on insert trigger. its successfully working also.

after that i have added security for asmx services.

```
<authorization>
<deny users="*" />
<allow users="basit, sss" />
</authorization>
```

i created below code and its working successfully.

but how to pass the asmx webservice security on below SQL code. This code is working fine without ASMX secuirty(username & password)

```
set @URL=N'http://localhost/Test/WebService1.asmx/Frm_SendNotification?LsM_Message='test'
EXEC @rc = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objServHTTP OUT
EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @objServHTTP, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL
EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @objServHTTP, 'send'
EXEC @rc = sp_OADestroy @objServHTTP
```

but how to pass asmx username and password

Thanks Basit.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting from: [How to logon webapi from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342690/how-to-logon-webapi-from-sql-server)

```
 EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'open', null, @methodName,
 @URI, 'false', @UserName, @Password
```