# VBA Code To Send HTTP GET Request With Authorization Not Working

Tags: http, ms-access, vba

I have been accessing a website and entering 3 parameters and an Authorization to get access to data. When processed, the data appears in a Responds Window on the website, and I manually select all and copy it to a text file. The Authorization Key is good for a day, and I just need to update the 3 parameters each time when I make a request.

I have to repeat this process for about 50+ times.

I have tried using this sample code from someone on this website over 1 year ago, and I have no errors, and it doesn't seems to connect.

I am perfectly happy trying to get it working by manually entering the authorization key code for now. This takes most of the coding out.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sUrl As String, sAuth As String

    sUrl = "https://cl.nnn.nnnn.com/api/tracking/game/play?gameId=2017121601&gamekey=57444&playId=51"
    sAuth = "NGS AKIAIX2XXXXXXXXXPOTKDQ:XXXXXXXXXXXkfmT7enl6I="

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sAuth
        .Send
        Debug.Print .ResponseText
        Debug.Print .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358550/xmlhttp-request-basic-authentication-issue

Comment: I would suggest you to try https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web . It will save you many headaches ...